# Android ListView ViewHolder only displaying one view

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm having a weird problem with my viewholders. I'm trying to create an activity that allows the user to choose multiple dates from datepicker dialog (this works) and then make a list of the chosen dates and add a timepicker for each of them. E.g 22-02-2014 14:00 (the 14:00 depicting a timepicker for that date). So if 5 dates were chosen, 5 rows would appear with each containing a chosen date and its own timepicker.

Currently creating the list from chosen dates works but timepicker won't appear no matter what I attempt. Only the textview containing the date is shown in the holder.

I've been searching for solution for several hours but I can't seem to find similar issues which indicates something is seriously wrong on my end. Just can't fathom what that might be.

The relevant code (omitting the activity itself since it works as supposed with list and all):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class RandomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
static Context mContext;
private static class ViewHolder {
    private View row;
    private TextView date;
    private TimePicker tp;      

    public ViewHolder(View row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date.setText(date);
    }
    public void initTp(TimePicker tp){
        this.tp = tp;
    }
    public void setHour(int h) {
        tp.setCurrentHour(h);
    }
    public void setMin(int m){
        tp.setCurrentMinute(m);
    }
    public TextView getDate() {
        if(date==null) {
            date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rr_date_item);
        }
        return date;
    }
    public TimePicker getTp() {
        if(tp==null) {
            tp = (TimePicker) row.findViewById(R.id.rr_tp);
        }
        return tp;
    }
}

private static RandomListAdapter instance = null;
private ArrayList<String> items;

public RandomListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
    mContext = context;
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void updateList(ArrayList<String> l){
    items = l;
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String s = (String)items.get(position);
    ViewHolder vH = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rr_row_layout, null);
        vH = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        vH.date = vH.getDate();
        vH.tp = vH.getTp();

        convertView.setTag(vH);
    }
    else {
        vH = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }       
    if(vH != null && s != null) {
        vH.setDate(s);
    }
    return convertView;
}

public static RandomListAdapter getInstance(Context mContext) {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new RandomListAdapter(mContext);
    }
    return instance;
}

}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" >


        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:id="@+id/rr_date_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/rr_tp"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance and my apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

on your `TimePicker`. Change the `height` to `wrap_content`. Only the `width` needs to be `0dp` when using `weight`.